# How to convert Ajax get request to Angular 7 http get request

Tags: angular, ajax

I have a backend RestApi method that returns a List of strings. My Ajax call to get the list of strings is:

```
var url = "api/list/"
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType : "json",
    processData : false,
    success: function(data) {
           downloadData(data);
});
```

The downloadData method iterates through the list I get back and downloads the data as a csv file. I want to reuse this method so I was wondering if there is a way to convert that call to an Angular 7 http get request that will work with my front end which returns a List of strings. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried the HttpClient's `get` method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in angular you can use HttpClient module like this code sample to send get request.

```
this.http.get<string[]>('https://yourdomain/api/list').subscribe(data => {
  this.downloadData(data);
})
```